# Проблема установки opencv-python на 3 питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, opencv, pip

При установки модуля `pip install opencv-python'` все прошло успешно. Открыл Python 3 и подключил модул `import cv2` мне написало что модуля не существует:

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Повторил то же самое, только со python 2 все отлично работает. Прошу помогите, как исправить

Comment: Устанавливайте через `pip3` для 3.

Comment: Спасибо помогло, но только для Python 3.6.8. Нельзя сделать это для Python 3.7(т.к написанно что opencv поддерживает и эту версию)

Comment: @mkkik Впринципе вы можете уже оформить как ответ, но если поможете еще с этим разобраться, будет классно

Comment: Можно создать ссылку на pip 3.7 и по команде pip37 будет работать pip от python 3.7, а лучше использовать venv

Comment: @Log1c0, не вижу смысла писать это в ответ. Ваша проблема неоднократно обсуждалась на ruSO. Если у вас есть другой вопрос, то его лучше задать как отдельный.